# Magento enterprise extension cost

Tags: magento2, extensions, magento-enterprise, magento2-cloud

I am working on an enterprise project. Actually getting started. But I want to know or understand why the Enterprise extension are costing triple the amount of community of an extension. What is the basic difference that it makes?

The question shared was asked 4 years ago. This is Magento2. Plus, how to verify if the cost that the vendor is asking is actually worth the price?

Note:-

From my experience I have asked various vendors if the extension is verified on Enterprise no one is giving a satisfactory answer. What I have came to the conclusion is that extension companies are charging extra money from enterprise customers just because they know that they can pay. And if the company has actually got verified then Magento should give some license to sell. So that buyer knows that its not fake but a genuine product.

Comment: That is a 5 years old question!!!

Comment: Yes, but why would that have changed?

Comment: Well, why can't . The whole Magento2 structure is changed search engine changed. How can I trust the credibility of the vendor. They asking tons of money that too without a single demo for 1000$ worth money

Comment: I mean can anyone from the people liking the comment or posting the question as duplicate tell me if it wise to spend 1000$ without seeing what we are buying and Just on the basis of ages old post. It may be incorrect platform to ask the question but no vendor is giving a proper response.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answers from [Extensions charging more for enterprise?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7267/extensions-charging-more-for-enterprise) are still valid.

For the second question - "How to verify ..."

I think there is no right answer. If the vendor offers great support, it may be worth the money. If they produce good code (in quality) it may be also worth.

If I need to buy an extension, I only buy from bigger extension providers where i know the code quality, where source code isn't decoded, where i have good support and free updates.

In this case it's OK for me to spend some more bucks.

Comment: Maybe what you are saying is correct but if anyone who is professional, no one should go by trust. Unless magento takes responsibility and give a proper license key to sell.

Comment: Question can be why magento should take the responsibility well because vendors are asking more because of magento enterprise